# What is the value of $\binom{n}{n+1}$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Is it equal to zero or is it undefined? I set up a summation involving something that ended up creating an n-1 choose n term, and I was wondering if I could just change the bounds of the summation.

Comment: There are zero ways to choose $n+1$ items from a set containing $n$ items.

Comment: Although I agree with abiessu's comment, I think that his comment represents the *start* of the analysis, rather than the end of it.  The phrase " I set up a summation involving something that ended up creating an n-1 choose n term", *suggests* to me that something has **gone wrong** in your analysis; perhaps I am mistaken.  Normally, when I determine that one aspect of a problem can be represented by $\binom{n}{k}$, the representation only has *meaning* (for my attack of the problem) when $k \in \{0, 1, 2, \cdots, n\}.$  ...see next comment

Comment: It is true that more unusual problems require that this restriction be relaxed.  I suggest that you take a closer look at what your summation is supposed to represent to see if you have a subtle error in your analysis.

Comment: When manipulating summations involving binomial coefficients it is not uncommon to get terms of that kind; they are $0$, as are terms $\binom{n}k$ with $k<0$.

Comment: See "Extensions" in the Wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle

Answer (score 3):

If $k$ is a whole number between $0$ and $n$, then the following formula is fine ...
\begin{eqnarray*}
\binom{n+1}{k+1}=\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k+1}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Let $k=n$ ...

Comment: @SamielLui For $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}, n > 2,$ let $U$ denote the set $\{0, 1, 2, \cdots, n\}$.  I agree that **artificially** construing $\binom{n}{n+1}$ to equal $0$ allows the formula to be true when the variable $k$ in the expression $\binom{n}{k}$ exceeds the boundaries of $U$.  However, the formula was initially *proven* algebraically under the constraint that $k \in U$ and $0 < k < (n-1)$.  The artificial (nonsensical ?) convention that $0! = 1$ was adopted so that the formula would also hold true for $k=0$ and $k=(n-1)$.  To me, this seems like one artificiality on top of another.

Comment: @SaimielLiu The point of my previous comment is that the 2nd artificial convention amounts to starting with Pascal's triangle, extending each row with zeroes on both the left and right sides, and then observing that the formula that each number is the sum of the two numbers above it still holds true.  Normally, when you are applying (for example) $\binom{n}{k}$ to one aspect of a math problem, it is because this application *makes sense* to you (i.e. is construed to have significance).

Comment: @SamielLiu When $k$ exceeds the bounds of $U$, that is when $k < 0$ or $k > n$, then, depending on the math problem, it may become more difficult to attach significance to the construance.

Comment: @user2661923 The definition $\binom xk = \frac{x(x-1)(x-2)\dots(x-k+1)}{k!}$ makes sense for any $x \in \mathbb C$ and any nonnegative integer $k$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov For $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ and $k \in \{0,1,\cdots, n\}, ~\binom{n}{k}$ can be *construed* to represent the # of ways of selecting $n$ things, $k$ at a time.  Certainly, your definition is unambiguous and therefore usable.  Further, my guess is that theory can be developed based on your definition.  I am also guessing that the developed theory facilitates solving math problems.  **However**, what does $\binom{x}{k}$ actually represent, apart from the precise definition that you have given?

Comment: @MishaLavrov Also, don't you need a special rule to explain what happens to the numerator, under your definition of $\binom{x}{k}$, when $k= 0$?

Comment: @user2661923 I'm not sure why you object to $0!$ as nonsensical: even if we stick to combinatorial interpretations, $0!$ is clearly the number of bijections between two $0$-element sets.

Comment: @MishaLavrov **Yes**, which is why I attached a "?" to the adjective.  In the world of choosing $n$ things, $k$ at a time, it makes sense that $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}.$  Also, $\binom{n}{n} = 1$, makes sense.  So you can interpret $k!$ as the # of ways of permuting $k$ things.  Under this definition (as well as yours), $0! = 1$ makes sense.  However, under the alternative definition, $k! = k(k-1)\cdots(1), 0!=1$ is nonsensical.  A *possible* case can be made that $0!$ was initially arbitrarily set to 1 merely to facilitate the formula in Donald Splutterwit's answer.